# Unable to create Mat using OpenCV.js

Tags: javascript, opencv, image-processing, face-detection

I am using opencv.js and I get an error when I call the constructor of Mat class

```
new cv.Mat(100, 100)
```

---

```
opencv.js:30 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'width' in 100
    at Object.toWireType (opencv.js:30)
    at Mat.constructor_body (opencv.js:30)
    at Mat.<anonymous> (opencv.js:30)
    at new Mat (eval at createNamedFunction (opencv.js:30), <anonymous>:4:34)
    at Object.window.cv.onRuntimeInitialized (SplashView.vue?f176:10)
    at doRun (opencv.js:30)
    at run (opencv.js:30)
    at runCaller (opencv.js:30)
    at removeRunDependency (opencv.js:30)
    at receiveInstance (opencv.js:30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the constructor the wrong way

```
let mat = new cv.Mat(size, type);
```

Your size should be an object with 'width' and 'height' properties instead

```
size = {'width': 100, 'height': 100}
```

or [100, 100]

Example:

```
let mat = new cv.Mat([100, 100], cv.CV_8UC3)
```